# Extensions of fast-growing hierarchy

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

In recent weeks, I have been fascinated by the possible extensions of the fast-growing hierarchy. But is there a way to define it for all recursive ordinals? I saw a statement of this sort on googology, but they don't provide any additional details.
I have the following questions:

1. Is there an extension of FGH to all recursive ordinals (and beyond)?
2. I have also read that the Busy Beaver function is on level $\ f_{\omega_1^{CK}}(n)$ of FGH. Do you know some proof of this?

Comment: A fairly recent Math.SE question that has some similarity: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381330/computable-function-not-outgrowed-by-fast-growing-hierarchy

Comment: For (1), not really: check this [answer to a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2178223/125463), and for more details about the _subrecursive stumbingblock_ see Section 5.1 of [_Proofs and Computations_ by Schwichtenberg and Wainer](https://books.google.fr/books?id=C0avFThF2SgC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=subrecursive+stumbling+block&source=bl&ots=1b0Cj7kj1f&sig=m5e37CKELQ5MV0Wu-mxWAfaGoIA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7osOslJDWAhUEBBoKHeOYAKAQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=subrecursive%20stumbling%20block&f=false)

Comment: I am deleting my comments as I do feel that perhaps they are a bit detracting to the OP's main question. Also there is some imprecision in my statements (due to very nature of comments) that might detract further. I may possibly post a separate and precise question (which kind of came to my mind after reading this question).

Comment: It seems to me that it should be straightforward to extend the fast-growing hierarchy by functions $f_a$ for ordinal *notations* $a$. But different notations for the same ordinal will give different functions.

Answer (score -2):

The first question is easy, if the ordinal has a well ordered set, then yes.  So if made by recursion, then it is well ordered (some caveats there), but broadly yes.  Extends to all up to the Church Kleene Ordinal

I do not think the Busy Beaver Function is limited by the Church Kleene Ordinal.  The Busy Beaver Function is on the order of uncountability as it cannot be calculated by any Turing Machine.

The Church Kleene Ordinal is countable and is the supremum of all recursive ordinals.
https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/Church-Kleene_ordinal

The Busy Beaver Function quickly breaks the bounds of even ZFC theory
"Wythagoras proved Σ(38)>fω2(167),  Σ(64)>fω2(4,098) and Σ(85)>fε0(1,907).

Wythagoras also showed that Σ(61,6)≫H(3) and LittlePeng9 proved Σ(134,7)≫U(3) where H and U are Chris Bird's functions. Wythagoras has also shown that Σ(38,3)≫fε0(374,676,379).

BB(1,919) is the smallest known value of the busy beaver sequence that is independent of ZFC. The first such TM constructed had 7,918 states."

Comment: *"The Busy Beaver Function is on the order of uncountability as it cannot be calculated by any Turing Machine."* Using purely recursive well-orders, it is possible to give a very simple example so that the function $f_\omega$ grows faster than any computable function. "Most likely" BB can be surpassed easily just by using recursive well-orders and on a "very small" ordinal (something close $\omega^3$ etc.). I am nearly sure but I used "most likely" just because I haven't explicitly thought about that kind of example.

Comment: @SSequence A recursive well-order on $\omega^3$ (or any other recursive ordinal) and fundamental sequences derived from it will lead to $f_{\omega^3}$ computable. If you wish to pick sequences for different limit ordinals independently (and not uniformly from a single well-order) then you can do with just $\omega^2$ though. You can in fact exceed any function whatsoever by choosing FSes up to $\omega^2$ suitably (and still keeping them all recursive)

Comment: The first half of this answer is misinformed (as for instance the other comments indicate). The second half is irrelevant.

Comment: @Wojowu *"If you wish to pick sequences for different limit ordinals independently (and not uniformly from a single well-order)...."* Yes I think I should have mentioned it explicitly. What I assumed implicitly was that with the recursive well-order we fix a "default/simple" way of selecting (fundamental) sequences for all limit elements (using just that single well-order). It seems what can be said precisely would depend on details (to some extent). For example, we can drop the condition of well-order being recursive or choose to keep it etc.

Comment: Though I should also add that some confusions of this type are quite common for someone who is relatively new to these topics (though the confusions may not be the same for everyone). And hence one shouldn't be discouraged because of that. I used to have some fairly significant confusions till about 4 years ago (and probably an year or so before that I used to think $(\omega_{CK})^2$ as $\omega_1$ ..... which is probably more than just a "significant" confusion :P).