# Question Regarding Hierarchies of Functions

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, proof-theory

The more precise statement of this question is partly inspired by the question [Extensions of fast-growing hierarchy](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280449/extensions-of-fast-growing-hierarchy). However, I didn't want to derail the original question (since the OP may have completely different set of questions in mind), so I am posting this as a separate question.

Suppose we are given some fixed family of fundamental sequences for limit ordinals up till $\omega{_C}{_K}$, but not necessarily including $\omega{_C}{_K}$ itself. Now suppose the family of sequences is described by the function $F:\omega{_C}{_K}\times\omega \rightarrow \omega{_C}{_K}$. The obvious meaning of $F(\alpha,n)=\beta$ is that the n-th term of the fundamental sequence for $\alpha$ (whenever $\alpha$ is a limit) is $\beta$. When $\alpha$ is not a limit we may take $F(\alpha,n)=0$ as convention for example.

I use the same definition of notation function $address:\alpha \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ as in my other threads (not mentioning it here to avoid excessive repetition): [Finite Number of Registers and Computable Well-Orderings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279199/finite-number-of-registers-and-computable-well-orderings). It is just below the bold heading **First Part**.

Now for any limit ordinal $\alpha$ define the function $F_\alpha:\alpha\times\omega \rightarrow \alpha$ (sorry I forgot to add that the function $F_\alpha$ is suitably defined unique "restriction" of the function $F:\omega{_C}{_K}\times\omega \rightarrow \omega{_C}{_K}$). That is $F_\alpha(\beta,n)=F(\beta,n)$ for all combinations of $\beta$ and $n$ in domain of $F_\alpha$. Given any computable well-ordering (on $\Bbb{N}$) of order-type $\alpha$ ..... with corresponding address function as $address:\alpha \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ ..... we define the representation function $f_\alpha:\Bbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ of $F_\alpha$ as:
$$f_\alpha(address(x),address(y))=address(F_\alpha(x,y)) \quad for\,all\,\,x\in\alpha,\,y\in\omega$$

We can say that the function $F$ is **step-recursive** (sorry that's not the best term ... I can't think of a better one) iff for arbitrarily large limit ordinals $\alpha<\omega{_C}{_K}$ there exists atleast one recursive well-ordering (on $\Bbb{N}$) of order-type $\alpha$ such that the representation function of $F_\alpha$ is recursive in the given well-ordering.

Now suppose we define some specific hierarchy (say fast growing hierarchy) corresponding to the function $F$. Denote the function that is formed as a result of the hierarchy at level $\alpha$ as $g_\alpha: \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$. Define the collection of function $G$ as:
$$G=\{\,g_\alpha\,|\,\alpha<\omega{_C}{_K}\,\}$$

Now suppose that the function $F$ is step-recursive. We have the following two questions:

(1) Does there exist a function $F$ such that the functions contained in $G$ are all recursive and there is no total recursive function that dominates all the functions in $G$?

(2) Does there exist a function $F$ such that the functions contained in $G$ are all recursive and there exists a total recursive function that dominates all the functions in $G$?

Also how sensitive would the answer to these two questions be to specific definition of hierarchy (say replace fast-growing with slow-growing). Any kind of references will also be quite welcome.

**Few Extra Questions**

Can we describe somewhat more general techniques that can help us to answer the previous two questions above, given some $F$ that is step-recursive (as opposed to finding only one example of such an $F$). Do the two problems above becomes trivial if we drop the requirement for $F$ to be step-recursive (and how)?

P.S. I don't have any personal experience with hierarchies at all. However, this question has been on my mind for some time (thought the precise description wasn't). Also if the proof-theory tag isn't quite appropriate for this question then it can be removed.